# Harvesting a project in WiX 4: HarvestFileAutogenerateGuids seems to be ignored

Tags: wix, wix4

I have an installer project made in WiX 3.x and I would like to convert it to WiX 4. It harvests a number of projects in a solution.
As specified in the manual (https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/heat/) I enabled the harvesting and added some HarvestProject elements, like:

`<HarvestProject Include="..\..\Source\MyProject.csproj" ProjectOutputGroups="Binaries;"/>`

It harvests projects and generates a number of fragments, having components like:

`<Component Id="MyProject.exe" Guid="*">`

Now I would like to have guids explicitly generated during harvesting because on later stages auto generating guids gives me some issues. Following Wix 4 manuals it should be controlled by HarvestFileAutogenerateGuids and HarvestProjectsGenerateGuidsNow being set to true or false. Like:

`<HarvestProject Include="..\..\Source\MyProject.csproj" ProjectOutputGroups="Binaries;"  HarvestProjectsGenerateGuidsNow="true"/>`

But playing with all possible combinations of these 2 properties I always get the same wxs file generated with Guid="*" Looks like these properties are completely ignored.

Is there a way to generate explicit guids during harvesting in WiX 4? I'm new to WiX 4 so I may be missing something.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Is there any solution available ?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bug, so please file an issue at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/new/choose with a repro details.